# Assign a unique count to each row in the resulting table of a select statement

Tags: sql-server

Let's assume we have a simple database that has the following schema: **Article(Id, Body, AuthorId)** and **Author(Id, Name)**. Suppose that we want to develop a page where each author will be able to view his own posts only. There is only one requirement:

- When the author wants to see his posts, the SQL query should allow him to see a counter for each item, starting at 1.

**Example**
Here's a simple set up:
(1,"Hi",1), (2,"there",1), (3,"test",2), (4,"foo",1).

By executing some sort of SQL statement: `select count, body where authorid=1; 
we want to get:
(1,"Hi",1), (2,"there",1), (3,"foo",1).

**Question**
As you can see, the suggested statement wont work because **count** does not make sense yet. My question is, is there any way to assign a local count for each item  to produce the result above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER`, like this:

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY ID ASC) AS [Count],
    body 
FROM @Article AS A
WHERE authorid=1


Count                body
1                    Hi
2                    there
3                    foo
```

Comment: And if you return more than one author, `OVER (PARTITION BY AuthorID ORDER BY ID)`.